# How do i use the second function i've created?

Tags: octave

It's giving me an error ( value on right hand side of assignment is undefined) when i want to call the second function that i've created on line 12

```
function cosaprox
   clc, clear
   %d es el incremento y c sera la aproximacion del coseno
   d = pi/100;
   c = 0;
   tol = 0.2;
   i = 0;
   flag = true;
   %Aproximacion del cos
   while flag
      %Iteracion de la sumatoria
      x=facto (2*i)
      i+=1
      if abs(c - cos(2*pi))>= tol
         flag = false
      else
      endif
      
   endwhile
disp (c)
   
end 
function facto (x)
   if x==0;
      x=1;
   endif
   for h = 1:x-1
   x = x*h;
endfor
end
```

Comment: Sorry for my english

Comment: I’m removing the [matlab] tag because this is an Octave-specific question. This code doesn’t run in MATLAB.

Comment: You should never use `clc` and `clear` inside a function. `clear` also doesn’t have an effect there because there are no variables defined yet at  that point.

Comment: Your error is because `facto` doesn’t return a value. You need to say `function x = facto(x)`. Then the return value is whatever the value of `x` at the end of the function.